# Mongocxx getting value of retrieved db document

Tags: c++, json, mongodb, mongo-cxx-driver

I'm currently working on project, where I need to retrieve value from Mongo db record. Currently I can retrieve values using 'get_utf8().value.get_string()' for string values in document, but specifically 'expires_in' value, which is not enclosed in double quotes crashes code:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("61ffc0e17b589b87520ce6a1"), "access_token" : "<hidden>", "expires_in" : 7200, "token_type" : "Application Access Token" }
```

As an example to retrieve 'access_token':

```
mongocxx::collection col(mongocxx::database);
mongocxx::options::find opts;
opts.limit(1);
auto cursor = col.find({}, opts);
auto t = *cursor.begin();
// This code retrieves 'token_type' as expected
std::cout << "token_type : " << t["token_type"].get_utf8().value.to_string() << std::endl;
// This code isn't working neither for 'get_utf8', nor 'get_double()', nor
// 'get_int64()' and many others I looked into
std::cout << t["expires_in"].get_utf8().value.to_string() << std::endl;
```

Crash example:

> token_type: Application Access Token terminate called after throwing
> an instance of 'bsoncxx::v_noabi::exception'   what():  expected
> element type k_utf8 Aborted

Would appreciate any ideas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, somehow skipped one of the types & it worked:

```
std::cout << t["expires_in"].get_int32().value << std::endl;
```

Thanks